# Escape all text in a echo command

Tags: batch-file

I'm making text art in a batch file is there a way escape all of the vertical bars in the echos?

Not using `^`s the carets set the lines of text off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some options. There are more, but it depends of the real needs

```
@echo off

    :: Using delayed expansion
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "x=|| this is delayed expansion test           ||"
    echo(!x!
    echo(
    endlocal

    :: Using escaping
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    set "x=|| this is escaping test                    ||"
    echo(%x:|=^|%
    echo(
    endlocal

    :: Reading the data from the current file
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%x in ('findstr /r /c:"^:::1:" "%~f0"') do echo(%%y
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%x in ('findstr /r /c:"^:::2:" "%~f0"') do echo(%%y

    exit /b

:::1:||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
:::1:||                                          ||
:::1:|| this is a test                           ||
:::1:||                                          ||
:::1:||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

:::2:||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
:::2:||                                          ||
:::2:|| this is another test                     ||
:::2:||                                          ||
:::2:||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```